# Create Unauthenticated/Guest User Landing Page Community Builder

Tags: community, lightning-community, site.com, experience-builder-page

When users visit my Customer Community, I would like them to be presented with a "Landing Page" created in "Experience Builder", the documentation here is really and the settings are really thrown all over the place. As of Spring '20 Release.

1. I create my page in Experience Builder (I called it "Welcome"), it appears under `My Pages`, I set `Page Access` to `Public`[image]
2. I save the page and "Publish"  [image: published salesforce experience builder page]
3. Under "Settings", "Community Details" I ensure the community is publically available  [image]
4. Under "Workspaces" -> "Administration" -> "Settings" (I am still in Status: "Preview", *not sure if this has any effect*)
5. "Workspaces" -> "Pages", **Community Home**  (assuming this is where I want my users to land),
6. I select "Experience Builder Page", however, when I attempt to enter the name of my Experience Builder Page, "Welcome", it is not found. I have two options "main" and "login"

I find these appear to have something to do with "Site.com Community" under *Site Pages->Landing Pages* but they are *special* in that I can't seem to create a new that is a "Lightning Page"?, Also I have no page named "main" in my *Experience Builder* 
[image] 
[image]

So how do I accomplish this in this **RATS NEST** of settings?